# My app crashes when I try to play music in activity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, logcat

I've created a class called MusicPlayer.

```
public class MusicPlayer {
    public static MediaPlayer player;
    public static void SoundPlayer(Context ctx,int raw_id){
        player = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.music);

         player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
         player.setVolume(100, 100);

         //player.release();
         player.start();
    }
}
```

But my app keeps crashing when I try to acces it from my activity.

I just call it like this, inside the onCreate:

```
MusicPlayer.player.start();
```

I have the log cat error, and I can see that it complains about the; MusicPlayer.player.start(); in my activity. But I can't seem to understand the error.

```
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745): Process: com.comrades.rocketeer, PID: 1745
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.comrades.rocketeer/com.comrades.rocketeer.LaunchScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at com.comrades.rocketeer.LaunchScreen.onCreate(LaunchScreen.java:16)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-04 07:45:57.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     ... 11 more
```

I hope that you can help me out. And spot, what it is that I'm doing wrong.

LaunchActivity per request:

```
package com.comrades.rocketeer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.comrades.rocketeer.R;

public class LaunchScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        MusicPlayer.player.start(); //line 16

        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int logoTimer = 0;
                    while(logoTimer < 4000){
                        sleep(100);
                        logoTimer = logoTimer +100;
                    };
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.plambech.CLEARSCREEN"));
                } 

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        logoTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post `LaunchScreen` and indicate line 16 of that

Comment: What is line num 16 of your LaunchScreen.java class??

Comment: Line 16 is this = MusicPlayer.player.start();

Comment: I think you have not initialize MusicPlayer.player before calling MusicPlayer.player.start();

Comment: You should call MusicPlayer.SoundPlayer(context, raw_id); from onCreate().

Comment: You are trying to start player before it is initialized. Please, do it as Siddharth Vyas has mentioned above. Additionally, make use of listener based approach. For e.g set onPreparedListener on your player and override OnPrepared method. When your player gets ready, onPrepared will be invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialized `MusicPlayer` class before used like:

```
MusicPlayer.SoundPlayer(this,R.raw.your_song);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public class LaunchScreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    MusicPlayer.SoundPlayer(context, raw_id); ;// Try this

    Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try{
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while(logoTimer < 4000){
                    sleep(100);
                    logoTimer = logoTimer +100;
                };
                startActivity(new Intent("com.plambech.CLEARSCREEN"));
            } 

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally{
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    logoTimer.start();
}
}
```

Hope this helps.